# Azure VM with VS and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to setup a development environment on an azure VM. I require Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2012. The problem is that after installing the SQL Server the performance of the VM decreases drastically. After booting up the VM and opening Visual Studio for the first time I have to wait approx. 10 minutes. After that I can close VS and reopen it in a matter of seconds.
I've tried some things described in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn133149.aspx (separate disk for sql, disabled georeplication for the storage account, enabled locked pages, enabled instant file initialization), but it does not seem to help.
Oh, I'm using the G1 size (ssd disk).

Any suggestions how to improve the performance?

UPDATE: Further testing has shown that the Sql Server is responsible for the poor performance. Any clues how to make this faster?

Comment: Try a D4 instance instead to get access to more Cores.

Comment: This question should be posted to ServerFault, since it's not a programming question. That said, I agree with @SimonW in that you should go for more cores. G series seems way beyond overkill. D4 (or DS4 with low latency network) might be the better choice.

Comment: From my experience adding more cores do not result in a high performance boost. I've also tested installing sql server on a striped data disk (4x25GB) - still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In fact Azure users who need storage performance like on their boxes with SSD have to use Premium storage account and  configure Storage Spaces (software JBOD in Windows Server 2012) inside a virtual machine.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2015/02/26/azure-disk-iops-and-virtual-machines-in-iaas-part-ii.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately azure premium storage is noticably more expensive than the standard one. And it biled in a different way - you pay for the disk size and not for the actual data on it.